# xpath filter - how to filter to the latest node record

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have an issue with filtering xpath on specified node to have only the latest record. In the example xml there s a rule that the very first record on each node is the most current information. I would like to filter all records which are not relevant (different than the first record).

The second rule is that i do not want to use date conditions to filter all job_information records after the very first one.

Normally I am using xpath tester with expression such like:
/queryCompoundEmployeeResponse/CompoundEmployee[(person/employment_information/job_information[1])]
which gives me only the first record of job information but here is does not work. Can you show me what is wrong with it?

Can you help me?

xml input with 3 job_information records

```html
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
  <CompoundEmployee>
    <id>11111</id>
    <person>
      <employment_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>2018-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>2016-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2013-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
      </employment_information>
    </person>
  </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

xml output I would like to have

```html
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
  <CompoundEmployee>
    <id>11111</id>
    <person>
      <employment_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
      </employment_information>
    </person>
  </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have always the same XML structure, you can try :

```
data=xmlParse("C:/Users/.../pathtoyourxmlfile.xml")
a=xpathSApply(data,"count(//job_information[1]/ancestor::*)+6")
b=xpathSApply(data,"count(//job_information)-1")*4+(a-1)

old=read_lines("C:/Users/.../pathtoyourxmlfile.xml")
new = old[-(a:b)]

writeLines(new,con = "new.xml")
```

Output (new.xml) :

```
<queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
  <CompoundEmployee>
    <id>11111</id>
    <person>
      <employment_information>
        <job_information>
          <end_date>9999-12-31</end_date>
          <start_date>2017-05-17</start_date>
        </job_information>
      </employment_information>
    </person>
  </CompoundEmployee>
</queryCompoundEmployeeResponse>
```